# Confusing TeamViewer use-case

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, teamviewer

So here's the layout of the problem: A friend of mine installs inverters (for solar installations). The inverter itself broadcasts it's own WIFI that you can connect to. This WIFI has no internet connection. Once you've connected to the inverter's WIFI, you can go to a particular IP in your browser and log in. Once logged in, you can tell the inverter to connect the the client's WIFI, by giving SSID and password of the client's WIFI. Once this is done, the inverter can communicate with the client's WIFI.

Problem is, my friend is not very computer literate, and asked if I could use TeamViewer to log into his laptop (when he is on site) and log into the inverter's WIFI for him, then set everything up. My question is: In order to use TeamViewer, the Laptop must be connected to the client's WIFI (to get internet), but in order to connect to the inverter, one must change the WIFI connection to the inverter's one. If this happens, then my connection to the laptop is broken. There is also a way to connect to the inverter directly using an ethernet cable and the laptop instead. Given all this, is it even possible for me to remotely set up the system for him, using TeamViewer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible if your friend's computer is (or can be) connected to his router
via cable, leaving the wifi available for the inverter.

Feasibility conditions are that your friend's computer will have two network
adapters, Ethernet and WiFi, and there should be no conflict between the IP address
range as used by the inverter and the local network.
For example, the router may use `192.168.0.x` but the inverter `192.168.1.x`.

Under these conditions, you may connect the WiFi to the inverter and then
browse to its IP address.
Windows will automatically detect it as belonging to the WiFi adapter
and pass it through correctly.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try what you suggested. If I give him a usb WIFI adapter to plug into the laptop, could that operate as the second adapter?

Comment: It could work, as long as there is no conflict on IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) from WiFi to Ethernet to inverter's control/command box on your friend's PC would make it possible, if said box has an Ethernet port.

Otherwise, in the absence of the inverter's WiFi communicating with the outside world, I don't see how, unless your friend temporarily bridges the client's Internet connection to the inverter's, but your friend would have to be able to do that on his/her own, without your help over TeamViewer.

You can also guide him/her via FaceTime or some such video conference tool, telling him/her to keep his/her phone strained on the inverter's connection interface.

EDIT: you could also ask your friend for his/her Windows logon credentials, then open a remote session on your friend's laptop, and pilot things from your own PC. That would work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Windows can handle a dual WiFi connection via two separate adapters, but it's worth a try. Are you supposed to be quarantined like the rest of us? :-)

Comment:  affirmative. full lockdown 

Comment: Same here, alas, but it's for the greater good. I hope. This coronavirus thing is downright scary...